# Buttons stop working once I leave the activity and return

Tags: android, android-button

I have a list of activities, each link to their own activity with a play and pause button. 
The play and pause button work, I leave the activity and then return and neither of the buttons work once I return.

I'm not sure what I have to do to make this work.

I am a newcomer to Java/Eclipse.

```
com.zaknorris.brainhacker.v1;

public class attentionbuilder extends Activity{

MediaPlayer mpAttention;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.attentionbuilder);

    final MediaPlayer mpAttention = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.attn);


    Button btnplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnplay);

    btnplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mpAttention.start();
            mpAttention.setLooping(true);

        }{;
    };{

    Button btnstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstop);

    btnstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mpAttention.pause();                
        }}
        );
    };
    }); 



    }
}
```

Comment: add your code in onResume method also. onCreate will be called only once. onResume will be called each time activity bring to front.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "a list of activities, each link to their own activity"?  Could the problem be originating to how the app is structured (how the activities are started)?

Comment: @eternalmatt 

The main activity (main menu) has a number of buttons, each button is linked to another activity to play and pause a particular sound.

Done by a click listener and a start activity - new intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lost control of your bracket and parenthesis:

```
            }{;
    };{
    ...
    }}
    );
};
});
```

I'm not sure how button `btnstop` receives it's OnClickListener, since the parenthesis try to compile it in your `btnplay` OnClickListener...

Try this:

```
    final MediaPlayer mpAttention = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.attn);
    Button btnplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnplay);
    btnplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mpAttention.start();
            mpAttention.setLooping(true);
        }
    });

    Button btnstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstop);
    btnstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mpAttention.pause();                
        }
    });
```

If the Buttons still lose functionality please post any code in your onPause(), onResume(), and onDestroy() methods.

**Addition**

You are also defining `mpAttention` twice, change this line:

```
final MediaPlayer mpAttention = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.attn);
```

to:

```
mpAttention = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.attn);
```

**Addition**

Before the Activity is destroyed you need to release the MediaPlayer, otherwise you'll have trouble when you recreate your Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mpAttention.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

If you want to automaticaly pause the playback when the user switches to another task: phone call, text message, etc:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(mpAttention.isPlaying())
        mpAttention.pause();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Interesting that his code didn't work with his btnstop being accidently contained within the scope of the btnplay's OnClickListener.  I would think that as long as findViewById returns the right View, it would still be set up correctly......maybe I'm over thinking this one.

Comment: Also, he said that the buttons work once. They don't work when he leaves the activity and returns to it.  I don't thinking setting up the Views needs to happen more than once at the beginning of the lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you for the code fix up, 

This way does not affect the buttons from working, it still works once but then not when returned. 

I have no onPause, onResume or onDestroy methods in my code because I tried but it made it force close all the time so I took them out, not sure if this may help my situation.

Comment: onResume was my first thought but I must had wrote the code wrong

Comment: My first hunch was the syntax. But I believe you are creating two different `mpAttention`s, which might affect resotring the Activity state. I updated my answer.

Comment: @eternalmatt I admit I didn't confirm that the (){} pairings was the culprit, it was my gut feeling from the code posted... It was sound advice in general and at the least improved readability.

Comment: I just fixed up the mpAttention to the suggested line but I am still having the same problem :(

Comment: I recreated your problem and posted the solution. Short answer: you must release your MediaPlayer resources before trying to create another instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
}{;
    };{
```

The above two symbols seems like new addition to Java...he he he... Jokes apart.... I think its just a careless mistake....

Here it is in proper manner:

```
btnplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mpAttention.start();
            mpAttention.setLooping(true);

        }
    });
```